# Error: Creating Purchase order in quickbook v3 PHP api

Tags: php, api, quickbooks

I am creating purchase order using Quickbooks V3 by following this package. https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

This is the response i am getting from above code.. **2020: [Required param missing, need to supply the required value for the API, Required parameter Line .DetailType is missing in the request]**

Following is my PHP Code

```
$PurchaseOrderService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_PurchaseOrder();

$PO = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_PurchaseOrder();
$PO->setVendorRef(78);
$PO->setDocNumber('1234');
$PO->setTxnDate('2016-07-27');

$Line = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
$Line->setDetailType('SalesItemLineDetail');
$Line->setAmount(20.0000 * 1.0000 * 0.516129);
$Line->setDescription('Test description goes here.');
$SalesItemLineDetail = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_SalesItemLineDetail();
$SalesItemLineDetail->setItemRef(22);
$SalesItemLineDetail->setUnitPrice(20 * 0.516129);
$SalesItemLineDetail->setQty(1.00000);
$Line->addSalesItemLineDetail($SalesItemLineDetail);

$PO->addLine($Line);

if ($resp = $PurchaseOrderService->add($this->context, $this->realm, $PO)) {
    return $this->getId($resp);
} else {
    print($PurchaseOrderService->lastError());
}
```

Comment: This is XML data of request http://pastebin.com/cZd9j1QL
This is XML Response http://pastebin.com/VBg24Yiy

Comment: Please post your code. Read the documentation. Post your XML request IN THE QUESTION not hyperlinked, and post the XML response IN THE QUESTION and not hyperlinked.

Answer (score 1):

Have you made any effort at all to read the documentation?

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/PurchaseOrder

Please read the documentation. The documentation makes it very clear that there are two types of valid `Line.DetailType` entries:

- Item-based expense line
- Account-based expense line

You are using neither of those. Fix your code so that you're sending the right data, and you won't get this error.